# How to use a local storage value in my variable?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have the following variable:

```
var board = {
    mainBoard: null,
    level: 'easy', // <- this one needs te be set using local storage
    cells: {},
    },
//etc
```

Here the level is pre-set to `easy`. Now I want to get this from local storage. If none is set/saved using local storage, the level should be set to `easy`. Else use the level saved in the local storage.

But how to do this?

What I have tried:

First get the variable level (I don't think this is wrong?):

```
var level = {
    if (localStorage.length != 0) {
        level = localStorage.getItem('gamelevel');
    } else {
        level = 'easy';
    }
;}
```

but I can't get this to work so that the level from the local storage is used in the variable at the top of this question. What is the correct way to do this?

More info:
I set the level item like this (this works):

```
localStorage.setItem('gamelevel', board.level);
```

and I get it using:

```
localStorage.getItem('gamelevel');
```

So the problem; how to use the level from local storage (if it has one)?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only accessing localStorage once, at load (as you should - it's a comparatively expensive feature to query repeatedly), and at the same time you're establishing your board variable, you can do it all in the object literal:

```
var board = {
    mainBoard: null,
    level: localStorage.getItem( 'gamelevel' ) || 'easy',
    cells: {},
},
```

`localStorage.getItem` returns `null` if queried for any item that's not already set - so if it has been set, `board.level` will be equal to whatever value was retreived, and if it hasn't been set, the `null` return moves on to the value after the [logical OR (`||`) - handy for setting default values](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/).

Using `localStorage.length` would also prevent you from storing any other information other than `gamelevel` and have your default work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help en the useful extra information. This seems to work, simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Break your accessors and modifiers in to functions, ie:

```
function SetLevel(level) {
    localStorage.setItem('gamelevel', board.level);
}

function GetLevel() {
    if (localStorage.length != 0) {
        level = localStorage.getItem('gamelevel');
    } else {
        level = 'easy';
    }
}
```

Comment: No; replace references to the level variable with GetLevel()